# XGBoost reproducible feature importance scores

Tags: python, xgboost

I have built an `xgboost` model, I have used `sklearn` `train_test_split` on the data as well. For `sklearn` I have used `random_state` and for `xgboost` I have set the seed. However, I get different results each time run the code to get feature importance. I am trying to run unit test on the code producing the feature importance thanks.

```
`params = {
        'alpha': 0.7, 'colsample_bytree': 0.9, 'eta': 0.05, 'gamma': 1.2,
        'lambda': 1.95, 'max_depth': 4, 'min_child_weight': 65,
        'subsample': 0.95, 'objective': 'binary:logistic', 'eval_metric': 'auc', 'booster': 'gbtree',
        'seed': 4, 'nthread': 20
    }`
```

Comment: It might help if you add relevant snippets of your code so that others can see what you have done and can reproduce your error.

Comment: From memory, if you use subsampling during model training (i.e. `'subsample': 0.95` and `'colsample_bytree': 0.9`) and/or early stopping you do not get reproducible results. Set subsample and colsample_bytree to "1" and disable early stopping and see if the results are reproducible.

Comment: Thanks @jerad_marmot it helped